# Is the zero matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Then for any invertible matrix $P$, we can say $P^{-1}\cdot 0 \cdot P=0$ ?

Comment: In fact, zero matrix is diagonal.

Comment: Of course you can say what you wrote in the body of the question, as the left hand side of that equality is evidently the zero matrix.

Comment: By the way: **please** do not ask your question in the title: the body should be a complete question (and in this case it isn't)

Comment: @Mariano: It is perfectly acceptable to ask the question in the title, if it is as short as this. The question should then be re-stated in the body.

Comment: The body should be self-contained.

Comment: @Mariano: That's not what you said.

Comment: I am sorry but is there a point to this?

Answer (score 7):

The zero-matrix is diagonal, so it is certainly diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a diagonal matrix is that it must have zeros everywhere except on its diagonal. This is true for the zero matrix. So the zero matrix is a diagonal matrix. By the definition of matrix multiplication $$P^{-1}\cdot 0 \cdot P = 0$$ is true for any invertible matrix.

Comment: Your explanation might be ambiguous. A diagonal matrix is a matrix where its non-diagonal entries are zero.

Answer (score 1):

What is the result of $P^{-1} \cdot 0$? What is the product of that with $P$?